# How to automatically start GoEthereum when Microsoft Windows starts?

Tags: go-ethereum

How can I config or set up my Geth so that whenever the operating system restarted, Geth automatically run again by the same config and initial commands and automatically it be synced to the network . Is it possible? and what should I do?

Geth version: 1.10.23-d901d853

OS: Windows Server 2019